# jboss has wrong time

Tags: jboss, time

Seems like a dumb question but I'm confused by this and haven't been able to figure it out.

My Jboss app server (4.2.2) running on my dev machine (ubuntu 810) is using the wrong time.

Basically all the logs etc show the time as being 1 hour behind what it really is. My system time and zone are setup properly.

I also tried using -Duser.timezone=xxx switch, didn't change anything.

Sort of confused here ... anyone else ever seen this or know what could be causing it??

Comment: Sounds like daylight savings time is being ignored somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read [DaylightSavingsTimeIssues](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/DaylightSavingsTimeIssues) on the JBoss Wiki. If your operating system time and local time zone are ok, look at the JVM level and try to update the TZDB (see [Timezones, Daylight Savings, and the Sun TZupdater for the Java Runtime Environment (JRE)](http://java.sun.com/javase/timezones/index.html) if you are using a Sun Virtual Machine).

Answer (score 0):

If your problem *is* related to daylight savings time, then this page should be helpful. Check to see whether your JRE is up to date.

[TZupdater for the Java Runtime Environment](http://java.sun.com/javase/timezones/)